# Laravel sum multiple withCount results

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I want to order by the sum of multiple whereCount results.

This is my whereCount:

```
$q->withCount(['ordered', 'favorites']);
```

I wan to sum these `ordered_count+favorites_count` and order by this result. I am not very good at using SQL so i need some help. If this is possible using eloquent query builder than that is even better.

Comment: can you post the relation code for ```ordered``` and ```favorites```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [orderByRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#orderbyraw) to order by the sum:

```
$q->withCount(['ordered', 'favorites'])
->orderByRaw('(ordered_count + favorites_count) desc')
->get();
```